# When an IP is assigned to a newly created OpenVPN interface, does it create a default route for the subnet of that IP?

Tags: linux, networking, routing, openvpn

I'm following [the tutorial to learn OpenVPN](http://backreference.org/2010/03/26/tuntap-interface-tutorial/).

by following the steps of the part: `let's try it`
I use OpenVPN to create an interface tun2, and assign an IP to it

```
sudo OpenVPN --mktun --dev tun2
sudo ip link set tun2 up
sudo ip addr add 10.0.0.1/24 dev tun2
```

then I use tcpdump to monitor the packets flowing through `tun2`

```
sudo tcpdump -i tun2
```

and I input `ping 10.0.0.2` on terminal, but I see nothing on tcpdump output, also the `ping` is stuck without outputing anything.

in the tutorial, it says since the tun2 interface is assinged an IP 10.0.0.1/24, then the ping packet with 10.0.0.2 should pass through `tun2` coz there will be a default route. But this doesn't happen in my case.

```
#sudo route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tun2
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0
```

And it is also strange that the ping is stuck without outputing anything. In the tutorial, the results should be like:

```
# ping 10.0.0.2
PING 10.0.0.2 (10.0.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.0.0.1 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.0.0.1 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
```

BTW:is it due to firewalls and iptables should be added?

Comment: If you want to see a packet with `tcpdump`, enable ipv4 forwarding: `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_foward`, then try again: you will see the packet leave the `tun` interface to go to the `eth0` interface. Still no reply, because 10.0.0.2 is not a public, routable address, but at least you will seethe IF come to life.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your tutorial is right about where the packet will go, but not very clear about why it goes there. Either you or the tutorial are confusing "default route" with "route created by default".

When you assign an IP address to an interface, a *subnet* route is created through it "by default". In your example, when you assigned 10.0.0.1/24 to tun2, it *did* create a corresponding 10.0.0.0/24 route<sup>1</sup>.

But a "default route" *specifically* means the least-specific-possible route – that is, `0.0.0.0/0` for IPv4 or `::/0` for IPv6. You **do not** get these routes automatically, and you often cannot as they typically need a gateway set, which is only known later.

---

So the routing table is correct. Your packets don't go through tun2 because tun2 is *not connected to anything*, as far as your example shows.

It is not enough to merely *create* a tun interface (just like it is not enough to add an Ethernet card) – you must also *connect* it to something. For Ethernet it obviously involves plugging in a cable, and for tun devices, a program must be running on the other end.

That is, you must actually *set up a VPN client* using OpenVPN, and tell it to use tun2 as the VPN device. (Of course you'll also need an OpenVPN server somewhere else.)

---

<sup>1</sup> (aka 10.0.0.0 mask 255.255.255.0 – but better use the `ip route` tool instead of `route -n`.)

Comment: I created `tun2` using `sudo OpenVPN --mktun --dev tun2` `sudo ip link set tun2 up` and then wrote a vpn client http://paste.ubuntu.com/12700613/ and run the client program. And it works as you said. But it seems to me that there are two tun devices created, one from the OpenVPN command and one from the client program. so where I'm wrong? why there are two devices? how are they corresponding to the same name `tun2`?

Comment: I'm not sure. How do _you_ know they're two separate devices?

Comment: I don't know whether they are two seperate devices or not, and how are the mechanisms between these two, so I'm asking about this.